# How to drop small partitions from Spark Dataframe before writing

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am partitioning a dataframe like so, based on the value in a column:

```
    val dfPartitioned = df.repartition(col("my_col"))
```

I'd like to remove partitions from the dataframe smaller than N rows.  How would I do that before writing out to disk?

Or will I have to filter out the ones I don't want before partitioning?

Comment: I guess you can use `.mapPartitions` for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before paritioning, by getting count over window, and then filtering by threshold:

```
val df = Seq(1, 2, 1).toDF("my_col")
val rowCountThreshold = 1

df
  .withColumn("colNumber", count("my_col").over(Window.partitionBy("my_col")))
  .where($"colNumber" > rowCountThreshold)
```

Output:

```
+------+---------+
|my_col|colNumber|
+------+---------+
|1     |2        |
|1     |2        |
+------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.  Couldn't get Wangbo's to work, probably error on my end.  Hopefully this is as or more efficient than after partitioning?  import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

Comment: Using partitioning to write different files for all records with different "my_col" values.

Comment: Guess, in such case, "repartition" must be last operation before writing.

Comment: I repartition(aColumn) after eliminating those groups below the threshold, and then when writing I also partitionBy(aColumn).  Not sure if both are necessary, but it's working great and performing well.

Comment: Guess, if "write.partitionBy" is used, then "repartition(aColumn)" is not neccesary.

Answer (score 1):

Partitioning and filter rows:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import sparkSession.implicits._

df.withColumn("cnt", count($"*").over(Window.partitionBy("my_col").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)))
  .where($"cnt" > N)
  .drop($"cnt")
```